# Trying to compare two dates...one from mysql DB stored as DATE and one using DateTime object

Tags: php, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I have been trying unsuccessfully to compare two dates using an if statement to then run another query and update a mysql database.  I'm not sure where I am going wrong.  If I use `procedural` and use

```
date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date30)));
```

Then I get an update of every field in the column boosterWithinDays.

If I try and use `DateTime` object

```
$boosterDate = new DateTime($row['boosterDate']);
$boosterDate->format("Y-m-d");
```

Then I get no update at all.  I've set some boosterDates to more than 30 days and some to less and nothing seems to work.

Here is the complete code:

```
    <?php
//date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$todaysDate = new DateTime('now');
$formattedDate = $todaysDate->format('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date90 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P90D'));
$date90 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date60 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P60D'));
$date60 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
$date = new DateTime ('now');
$date30 = $date->add(new DateInterval('P30D'));
$date30 = $date->format('Y-m-d');
//echo $date90;
//echo "<br />";
//echo $formattedDate;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM service;";

if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
}
while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
//Get all the rows and store them in an array
$firstQueryRows[] = $row;
}
foreach($firstQueryRows as $row){
//do a new query with $row
$patientID = $row['patientID'];
$serviceID = $row['serviceID'];
//$boosterDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $row['boosterDate'])));
//$date30 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date30)));
//$date60 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date60)));
//$date90 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $date90)));
$boosterDate = new DateTime($row['boosterDate']);
//$boosterDate->format("Y-m-d");
//$interval = $boosterDate->diff($date30);
$boosterDate = $boosterDate->format("Y-m-d");
var_dump($boosterDate > $date30);
echo "<br /><br />";
print "This is the booster date" . " " . ($boosterDate) . " ";
echo "<br /><br />";
print "This is todays date plus 30 days" . " " . ($date30) . " ";
if($boosterDate < $date30){
//echo "The date is less than 30" . " " . $row['serviceID'] . "<br /><br />";
//echo $date30 . "<br /><br />";
//echo $boosterDate;
echo "this is being shown because boosterDate object is less than date30 object";
$sql = "UPDATE service SET boosterWithinDays = 30;";
if(!$result = $con->query($sql)){
die('There was an error running the query [' . $con->error . ']');  
}
}else{
NULL;
}
}
//$date = $row['boosterDate'];
//$id = $row['patientID'];
//echo $date . " " . $id . "<br /><br />";
//echo date_default_timezone_get();

?>
```

Comment: Your calls to `->format()` are unnecessary

Comment: If I take out the ->format it just sets all the fields to 30 so I'm still stuck as to why when I'm comparing the two dates it isn't coming out correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It could be me, but since you are comparing 2 objects (DateTime), isn't it better to use the diff function and get the invert flag?

```
if ($boosterDate->diff($date30)->invert) {
    // other code    
}
```

Comment: From the php.net site http://ca3.php.net/m...tetime.diff.php you can do this.

 

$date1 = new DateTime($date);

$date2 = new DateTime($date);

 

Then from that point you can use a comparison operator for the two var's like <, >, or ==.  For some reason this isn't working in my code.  No matter true or false my field boosterWithinDays alwasy updates to 30.  I have no idea why the query runs when it's false.  Any help is much appreciated.

 

I have updated my code above to reflect the changes from the php manual.